# Is $L^2(\Omega )$ complete?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $L^2(\Omega )=\{X\mid \mathbb E[X^2]<\infty \}/_{\sim}$ where $X\sim Y\iff \mathbb P\{X=Y\}=1$. I know that $L^2(\Omega )$ is a inner product space, but is this space complete ?

Comment: can you define Cauchy sequences in this space ?

Comment: Isn't any LP space complete?

Comment: @Amr there are two ways to define $L^p, p \ge 1$ in analysis : as the completion of the continuous functions for the $\|.\|_p$ norm (so it is by definition complete) or as the space of all $|.|^p$ Lebesgue integrable functions (in that case it requires a proof that it is complete). Here we are in the second setting, with "$|.|^p$ Lebesgue integrable" replaced by "being a random variable with finite $p$ moment"

Comment: COmpleteness is true for all $L^p$ spaces over measure spaces, $p\in [1,\infty]$. It's a classical result sometimes known as [Riesz-Fischer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem). You can find it in most books of real analysis and introdcutory functional analysis. For instance, *Real Analysis* by Royden and *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* by Brézis (I don't remember if just the $\Omega=\Bbb R^n$ case in this one, though).

Comment: here I think the argument is that the convergence in $L^2$ [implies the convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4), so if $X_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in your space (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X_m|^2] \to 0$ as $\min(n,m) \to \infty$), then $X_n$ converges in probability to some r.v. $X$, by simply defining for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$ : $P( X \in E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P( X_n \in E)$

Comment: @user1952009 I was referring to the Riesz Fischer theorem